# Perl HTML::Strip->parse doesnt ignore &nbsp;

Tags: html, perl, html-parsing, strip

I am currently using perl HTML::Strip to extract text from my HTML file, however i have run into a minor problem with HTML specific spaces ie the " ". For some reason HTML::Strip->parse() doesnt seem to work in this instance. I know i can run the replace command later on. But i was checking to see if there another way i can accomplish this by tweaking the new() constructor? Thanks in advance

Perl Code:

```
my $hs = HTML::Strip->new();
my $line = join('',@htmlSource);
my $clean_text = $hs->parse( $line );
push @processedLines,  grep { /\S/ } split (/\n/,$clean_text);
foreach my $f  ( @processedLines ) {
  print "$f\n";
}
```

Sample Output:

```
CBD_UnitTest
MtrTempEst
MtrTempEst_Init1 (C1-Coverage: 100.00 %, 1 out of 1 Testcases passed)
LeadLagFilt (C1-Coverage: 100.00 %, 1 out of 1 Testcases failed)
                                        
                                        
AssMechFiltInit (C1-Coverage: 100.00 %, 1 out of 1 Testcases passed)
```

Sample Dataset:

```
<table bgcolor="white" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" bgcolor="white" border="0">
                    <tr bgcolor="#dcdcdc">
                    <td width="1%" bgcolor="white">
                        <img border="0" src="pictures/batch_module_notok.jpg"/>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="3" width="1%">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="-2" color="black">
                                    CBD_UnitTest
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%">
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%">
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%">
                        <img border="0" src="pictures/batch_check_notok.gif"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="white">
                    <td width="1%" bgcolor="white">
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%" bgcolor="white">
                        <img border="0" src="pictures/batch_module_notok.jpg"/>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="-2" color="black">
                                    MtrTempEst
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%">
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%">
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%">
                        <img border="0" src="pictures/batch_check_notok.gif"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#dcdcdc">
                    <td width="1%" bgcolor="white">
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%" bgcolor="white">
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%" bgcolor="white">
                        <img border="0" src="pictures/batch_ok.jpg"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <a href="#CBD_UnitTest:MtrTempEst:ts_MtrTempEst_Init1"><font face="tahoma" size="-2" color="black">
                                MtrTempEst_Init1 (C1-Coverage: 100.00 %, 1 out of 1 Testcases passed)
                            </font></a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%">
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%">
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%">
                        <img border="0" src="pictures/batch_check_ok.gif"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#FF0000">
                    <td width="1%" bgcolor="white">
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%" bgcolor="white">
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%" bgcolor="white">
                        <img border="0" src="pictures/batch_notok.jpg"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <a href="#CBD_UnitTest:MtrTempEst:ts_LeadLagFilt"><font face="tahoma" size="-2" color="white">
                                <b>LeadLagFilt (C1-Coverage: 100.00 %, 1 out of 1 Testcases failed)</b>
                            </font></a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%">
            <a name="LeadLagFilt_0"></a>
            &nbsp;                      </td>
                    <td width="1%">
            &nbsp;                      </td>
                    <td width="1%">
                        <img border="0" src="pictures/batch_check_notok.gif"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#dcdcdc">
                    <td width="1%" bgcolor="white">
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%" bgcolor="white">
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%" bgcolor="white">
                        <img border="0" src="pictures/batch_ok.jpg"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <a href="#CBD_UnitTest:MtrTempEst:ts_AssMechFiltInit"><font face="tahoma" size="-2" color="black">
                                AssMechFiltInit (C1-Coverage: 100.00 %, 1 out of 1 Testcases passed)
                            </font></a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%">
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%">
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%">
                        <img border="0" src="pictures/batch_check_ok.gif"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should be a bit more clear about what you mean by "its not working".

Comment: @TLP I have made an attempt to accurately rephrase my words. I have been very clear about the details, with the code, the data & my output. Please let me know if you require additional details. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer from the link to HTML::Entities above. Thx @edibleEnergy

```
use HTML::Strip;
use HTML::Entities;

my $hs = HTML::Strip->new();
my $line = join('',@htmlSource);
_decode_entities($line, { nbsp => "" }, 1);
my $clean_text = $hs->parse( $line );
push @processedLines,  grep { /\S/ } split (/\n/,$clean_text);
foreach my $f  ( @processedLines ) {
  print "$f\n";
}
```

I understand that we could just use the simple replace here (ie s/\ //g) But the above example works for instance with or without the ";" at the end. Please check the link provided in the @edibleEnergy's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed [HTML::Entities?](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities)
The [docs for HTML::Strip](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Strip) state:

"HTML::Strip will only attempt decoding of HTML entities if HTML::Entities is installed."

Comment: HTML::Entities is installed. But had not included in the code (ie I dont have the  'use HTML::Entities;' in my code), so it seems like i have to add it, can you please paste a code snippet for implementing this solution. thx